# How to model change over four time points on an ordinal variable where some participants have missing data at some time points?

Tags: repeated-measures, nonparametric, missing-data, ordinal-data, independence

#### Context

I am accumulating a data set that is starting to look like this:

1. I have about fifty individual animals (n=50) that I am studying over, say, a year
2. Every three months or so, I would measure each one and assign a score about their health. So at the end of the year I would theoretically have made four measurements/samples.
3. The scores are 0,1,2,3,4, with 0 being the best and 4 being the worst. I.e., I think I have ranked, discrete data?
4. However, everytime I only get to measure about 30 out of the 50 individuals. So at the end of the year, some animals may have been measured everytime, while others may have only been measured one or two times.

#### Question

Based on the above, what would be a good statistical test to see if the entire group of 50 individuals have changed over the four measurements? I am guessing some sort of repeated measurement, ranked non-parametric test might be suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a rank ordered logit. However, you need to take into account multiple observations per subject. You can do this with random effects model. Look up mixed rank ordered logit. That is one approach.

Comment: Would be great if you supplied some references for the models you are mentioning.

Comment: The ordinal package in R should be able to do that.  You will need to include time as a fixed effect to handle the unequal measurement times.

Comment: Search for rank ordered logit. These models are prety standard. Howver mixed rank ordered logits are not, and you may need to write your owb estimation routine in matlab, gauss, or other package. Thus an alternative to random effects could be fixed effects with dummy for each subject in the sample, or other similar.

Comment: Here are some examples. http://www.google.com/m/url?ei=b548TqDOGtOV9Aa1n_ihAQ&q=http://repub.eur.nl/res/pub/8533/ei2007-07.pdf&ved=0CBkQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNGosUab7wZRy2-bWfqadG4pPFtucQ and http://www.google.com/m/url?ei=b548TqDOGtOV9Aa1n_ihAQ&q=http://ageconsearch.umn.edu/bitstream/49518/2/AAEA%25202009.pdf&ved=0CCIQFjAC&usg=AFQjCNHyALtuXnpPice_ZCaSRTcV1nQK8A the first is a rank ordered logit with random effects and the second is an introduction to the models.